# what is the object data type in T-sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If Vb.net has an object data type for unknown variable what is the equivalent in T-SQL?

Example in T-sql

```
declare @variable as object?
```

Thanks

Comment: May I ask what for do you would need such a feature?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [SQL_VARIANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) comes close to what you're after:

`When handling the sql_variant data type, SQL Server supports implicit conversions of objects with other data types to the sql_variant type. However, SQL Server does not support implicit conversions from sql_variant data to an object with another data type.`

Here is a [list of all datatypes in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx).